Spark Delta Table dependencies are not resolved
I am create a delta table using python, but while we submit code jar dependencies are not resolved:
Below is my code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DecimalType, TimestampType, LongType
from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip
import os
import sys


print(sys.executable)
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

builder = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("DELTA TABLE EXAMPLE") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .config("spark.jars", "/home/spark/delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \

builder = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder)
spark = builder.getOrCreate()


#Schema
schema: StructType = StructType([
        StructField("ne_id", LongType(), True),
        StructField("init_time", StringType(), True),
        StructField("sum", DecimalType(12,2), True),
        StructField("total", DecimalType(12,2), True),
        StructField("avg", DecimalType(12,2), True),
        StructField("partition_date", StringType(), True)])



#df = spark.sql("select * from jnpm_ipsupport.test")
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema).load("/user/spark/test1.csv")

# Show the data
df.show()

print(df.printSchema())

df.write.format("delta").partitionBy("partition_date").mode("overwrite").save("/user/spark/examples/delta/test")

Using below submit command
spark-submit --master spark://sparkhost:7077 \
             --deploy-mode client \
             --executor-memory 1g \
             --executor-cores 1 \
             --num-executors 1 \
             --total-executor-cores 1 \
             --packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0 \
             --jars /opt/jnpm/delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar \
             --conf "spark.pyspark.python=/opt/jnpm/spark/venv/bin/python"  \
             Test_Hdfs.py

Below is the error :
jar dependency is provided while  submitting spark job
--packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0 
--jars /opt/jnpm/delta-spark_2.12-3.2.0.jar \
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/spark/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/spark/.ivy2/jars
io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-2fe5e051-7a80-4b84-ae1f-0f3e7d6b0470;1.0
        confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 525673ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
        :: modules in use:
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::WARNINGS     module not found: io.delta#delta-core_2.12;3.2.0

        ==== local-m2-cache: tried

          file:/home/spark/.m2/repository/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.pom

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;3.2.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          file:/home/spark/.m2/repository/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.jar

        ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

          /home/spark/.ivy2/local/io.delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;3.2.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          /home/spark/.ivy2/local/io.delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/jars/delta-core_2.12.jar

        ==== central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.pom

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;3.2.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.jar

        ==== spark-packages: tried

          https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.pom

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;3.2.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: io.delta#delta-core_2.12;3.2.0: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

        Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

        Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))

        Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/3.2.0/delta-core_2.12-3.2.0.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out))


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: io.delta#delta-core_2.12;3.2.0: not found]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1537)
        at org.apache.spark.util.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:964)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


I am using spark 3.5.0 with 5 node standalone cluster. And server is not having internet access.
